# Kafka Connector - JMSSourceConnector for Kafka topic

Tags: jms, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform, apache-kafka-connect

Does Confluent by default provides this JMSSourceConnector for Kafka topic.

Or we need to write custom connector for this?

I dont see any documentation on Confluent page on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Confluent doesn't provide source connector for JMS. Please find below link for number of connectors available in Kafka Connect.

http://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/

But developers can develop custom connectors for Kafka Connect. Please see the below URL for more information on how to write custom connectors for Kafka Connect.

http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.1/connect/devguide.html